# get information out of an API URL in JavaScript or react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have the main URL, they require authorizing header each time to access.

//console.log contains this data - accounts:[{categoryId:"some info"... }]

- api/v2/accounts

I need to get accountId and categoryId out of the first one to get further information then from the second I can get info for the other urls and so on
example:

1. /api/v2/accounts/accountId
2. /api/v2/accounts/accountId/categoryId
3. /api/v2/accounts/accountId/categoryId/feed/feedId
   etc.

What is the best way to do this?
I cannot fetch all at once since they depend on each other and none of them has all the info I need to progress with my app.
Also, if I fetch the first time to construct the next URL, I am assuming I need to fetch the new URL again to be able to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look at [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/)

It helps you build data fetching with your react app application state. This way, you'll be able to retrieve easily using your router params from URL and pass id and build your own URL dynamically when the state change.

You can solve this without it just by using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), `async/await` or some sort of tools such as [`async.js`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) depending on your stack and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Using async/await you can just run the requests one after another.

```
const getFeed = async () => {
  const accountIdData = await fetch(
    '/api/v2/accounts/accountId', 
    { headers: { 'Authorization': ...}
  );

  // Use accountIdData in the below url
  const categoryIdData = await fetch(
    `/api/v2/accounts/${accountIdData.id}/categoryId`, 
    { headers: { 'Authorization': ...}
  );

  // Use categoryIdData in the below url
  const feedIdData = await fetch(
    `/api/v2/accounts/${accountIdData.id}/${categoryIdData.id}`, 
    { headers: { 'Authorization': ...}
  );

  // Do something with feed data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You must fetch them consecutively.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const accountData = await axios.get("api/v2/accounts", accountToFetch)
  const accountId = await axios.get("/api/v2/accounts/accountId", accountData)
  const accountCategory = await axios.get("/api/v2/accounts/accountId/categoryId", accountData)
  ...
  // return data
}
```

Comment: Why do you bring `axios` ? `fetch` works everywhere , `react-native`.